# Any problems with importing classes from within __init__.py to make shorter import statements?

Tags: python

For the sake of organization, I keep each class in it's own file. I also have folders to separate GUI objects from regular objects. I was thinking of importing the classes from within the module's **init**.py to make imports neater.

For example, rather than have:

```
from myapp.widgets.preferencesdialog import PreferencesDialog
```

I would instead import `PreferencesDialog` from within `widgets/__init__.py` so that the rest of the app only has to do:

```
from myapp.widgets import PreferencesDialog
```

Am I going to run into any problems with that approach?

Comment: This is a pretty common approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that approach as long as you don't have multiple classes called `PreferencesDialog` in separate files that `myapp.widgets` is trying to put into its namespace.

Just avoid `from preferencesdialog import *` inside of `myapp.widgets`, you will need to explicitly add any new items to the `myapp.widgets` namespace but you will avoid all of the issues that go with `from ... import *`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I always avoid `import *` anyway. I like to be explicit with my imports.